# Dropdown height stopping on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a really basic jQuery dropdown menu. Problem is, when you hover on the dropdown and then mouseout and then mouseover again quickly it pauses but the UL height changes? Im guessing it has something to do with the stop() but I have not been able to rectify it.

jQuery below:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.HeaderNav > li').hover(function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
        }, function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
        });

        $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('HasChild');
        $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('Dropdown');

        $('li.Dropdown ul li').on('mouseover', function () {
            $(this).parent().prev().addClass('Active');
        }).on('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('Active');
        });
    });
```

I have created a fiddle for illustration purposes http://jsfiddle.net/JtYA2/1/

Any help / advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: Sure, if it is the CSS that is causing this?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the .stop() - this appears to rectify the problem for me in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I see this does work but the reason I put the stops there is to stop the ul sliding up and down a few time is you hover over it a few times quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtYA2/4/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.HeaderNav > li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).stop(true, false).slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('HasChild');
    $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('Dropdown');

    $('li.Dropdown ul li').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass('Active');
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('Active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out parameters of stop() function:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JtYA2/3/)**

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.HeaderNav > li').stop(true).hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).filter(':not(:animated)').stop().slideDown(300);
    }, function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
    });

    $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('HasChild');
    $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('Dropdown');

    $('li.Dropdown ul li').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass('Active');
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('Active');
    });
});
```

**[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.HeaderNav > li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).slideDown(300);
    }, function () {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
    });

    $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('HasChild');
    $('.HeaderNav li:has(> ul)').addClass('Dropdown');

    $('li.Dropdown ul li').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass('Active');
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('Active');
    });
});
```

I've removed stop() function calls and set the argument for slideUp() to 100.

Your issue is happening because the ul slideUp speed is slower than the speed you're re-hovering the ul with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

two solutions are there
1. $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(10); // reduse the timespan of slideup
or
2. it seems the issue is with the shadow of the last li, so if we remove that shadow of last li then it will work